# CFReport producing blank page

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9, cfreport

I'm moving a website from environment A to environment B. My current hangup is that the pre-existing ColdFusion Report isn't running.  The page loads with a blank html document, not a PDF file like the report is supposed to produce. i.e. If I view page source it is blank. No errors, no comments... nothing, just blank.

I don't know much about working with .cfr files or if anything is required on the server side to make them work.  The new environment is out of my control so I'll have to ask them for details if I'm not providing enough information.  The only thing I've found in any documentation is:

> At run time, you display the CFR file by using a ColdFusion server
>   that has ColdFusion Reporting enabled.

The only report setting I could find in the ColdFusion Admin is the max number of threads for cfreport. Am I missing something that would enable or disable reporting?

The reports have not been modified moving from one environment to the other. The .cfr file is being accessed directly and is configured in CFRB to allow that.

---

```
                                      UPDATE
```

---

I have tried running the reports on a different server within the new environment with the same result. Of course the sys-admins don't know of anyone else who's tried to use .cfr files so they are unsure as well.  I have even tried toggling the "Allow Direct .cfr Browser Invocation" option in the report but it didn't change anything.  For now, the reports will run if I use a cfreport tag to invoke them so I'm going to create a page to run the few reports with cfreport.  As this is isn't the solution to the original problem, I'm not going to answer my own question with this workaround.

TIA

Comment: I haven't used ColdFusion reporting, but my bit of Googling shows that you must have RDS enabled for reporting to work.

Comment: I think the RDS is just for report builder to help generate sample output similar to the way DreamWeaver lets you connect directly with RDS in order to drag/drop db tables and what not.  It can be handy for beginners but not required to use DreamWeaver.  The cfreport doc page doesn't say anything about RDS and the other references to RDS were in the "Creating Reports with Report Builder" docs.  In fact I found this on one of the pages suggesting it isn't even required, "Default RDS server configuration (used for Query Builder and Chart Wizard only; not required for report preview)"

Comment: Are the datasources on the two servers named the same? The datasource is stored in the CFR report directly. If you can confirm this, I can comment with some more detail if the datasources are not the same.

Comment: I believe the datasource is stored in a variable.

Comment: @Travis; are the datasources used in test and development the same?

Comment: @JasPanesar no, they are linked to different databases. the .cfr files work if they're being called from a cfreport tag like `<cfreport format="pdf" template="myReport.cfr">...</cfreport>` , they just don't work if they are called directly.  i.e. `domain.com/myReport.cfr?some_param=some_value`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have since moved another website from 32 bit ACF9 to 64 bit ACF11 Windows Server 2003 to 2012. I've come across a similar problem, though it presented differently. Instead of a blank white page I get an IIS 404.0 error.  After playing around with IIS handlers, confirming ACF wsconfig settings, removing/rebuilding IIS connectors with cfusion/bin/connectors tools and talking to a rather useless Adobe support person who didn't know what a .cfr file was, I've discovered that simply using `cfreport` to call the reports solves pretty much every issue I've had so far. For anyone else having this problem I would follow Adobe's example and just forget about this "feature" of CF. Build the output in HTML and use `cfpdf`, `cfdocument`, or `cfspreadsheet` for your output.

```
<!--- instead of --->
<cflocation url = "xyz.cfr">
<!--- use --->
<cfreport report = "xyz.cfr" format = "pdf"></cfreport>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <defaultDocument>
            <files>
                <clear />
                <add value="index.cfm" />
                <add value="home.cfm" />
                <add value="default.cfm" />
                <add value="Default.htm" />
                <add value="Default.asp" />
                <add value="index.htm" />
                <add value="Default.aspx" />
                <add value="index.html" />
                <add value="index.asp" />
                <add value="index.aspx" />
                <add value="index.cgi" />
                <add value="default.html" />
                <add value="home.htm" />
                <add value="home.html" />
                <add value="home.asp" />
                <add value="default.stm" />
                <add value="default.shtml" />
                <add value="default.php" />
                <add value="index.stm" />
                <add value="index.shtml" />
                <add value="home.stm" />
                <add value="home.shtml" />
                <add value="index.shtm" />
                <add value="_holding.htm" />
                <add value="_holding.asp" />
            </files>
        </defaultDocument>

        <directoryBrowse enabled="false" />
        <urlCompression doStaticCompression="true" doDynamicCompression="true" />
        <handlers>
            <remove name="cfrHandler" />
            <add name="cfrHandler" path="*.cfr" verb="*" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="C:\ColdFusion2018\config\wsconfig\1\isapi_redirect.dll" resourceType="Either" requireAccess="Script" preCondition="bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
        </handlers>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>`
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**